# Save Simple Http Authentication Credentials For Later Use

Tags: javascript

I'm trying something about simple http authentication and i made a login page and i'm using this javascript function to request a protected page from server and i'm receiving http 200 and i successfully receive contents of a page i want. Problem is after i receive http 200 if i want to go another protected page browser asks for credentials. I don't want to enter credentials on every page change.

If i not use my login page and i enter protected url to browser directly and i enter my credentials to browser's form : i can navigate other pages without entering credentials everytime.

```
function login()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("UsernameInput").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("PasswordInput").value;

    var authorizationBasic = window.btoa(username + ':' + password);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "protected/mainPageEN.html", true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic);
    request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'html');
    request.send();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () 
    {           
        if(request.readyState == 0) //Request not initialized
        {
                    alert("Not initializes");         
        }   
        else if(request.readyState == 1) //Server connection established
        {
                alert("Server connection established");           
        }
        else if(request.readyState == 2) //Request received.
        {
                    alert("Request received.");       
        }               
        else if(request.readyState == 3) //Processing request
        {
                alert("Processing request");              
        }   
        else if(request.readyState == 4) //Done
        {
                if(request.status == 200) //OK
                {
                    alert(window.location.hostname);

                    //Set cookie
                    var header = "Basic " + authorizationBasic;
                    document.cookie = "Authorization=" + header;

                    window.location = "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/protected/mainPageEN.html";

                }
                else if(request.status == 403) //Forbidden
                {
                    alert(request.statusText);
                    alert("Forbidden");
                }
                else if(request.status == 404) //Not found
                {
                    alert(request.statusText);
                    alert("Not Found");
                }
                else
                {
                alert(request.status);
                    alert(request.statusText);
                }
        }   
    };  
}
```

Comment: Obviously, sometimes it is *not* desirable to save credentials -- it depends on the app, security for your organization, end-goals, sensitivity of the data displayed by the app (if any)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are in need of a some sort of an authetication mechanism in your project. Saving credetials for later use is very risky and not recomended. Since you haven't mentioned the server side programming language you are using it is not possible to recommend what to use. However, you must do some researching in this area along side your server side programming language / framework.

Let's say you want to save something non-sensitive temporarily in the client side, you can use cookies, localstorage or webstorage.

**Cookies** - Cookies are small pieces of information websites store on your computer. Cookies only contain bits of text, not anything else. The text can be a user ID, session ID, or any other text. [Read more](https://www.howtogeek.com/119458/htg-explains-whats-a-browser-cookie/)

**sessionStorage** - maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session (as long as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores). [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

**localStorage** - The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions. localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

It is also worth checking the browser compatibility and the maximum size supported by those storages by various different browsers.

I hope this helps,
Thank you.